# How to set vue 3 with router from subfolder

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I installed fresh vue 3 app with cli, containing also vue router.

On my web I have put builded files into www/dist sub folder. Then in my php index file I linked all js/css files to /dist folder manually.

I have an image in component

```
<img class="discord-icon" src="@/assets/discord.png">
```

When I set publicHtml = '/dist' , everything works even image is shown, but for some reason my homepage gets redirected from original "www.page.com" to "www.page.com/dist"

I would like to have default "www.page.com" at homepage but also with working image, how can I achieve that ?

Edit :
My router config (default from Manual cli install with router)

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home
  }
]


const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
});
```

UPDATE :
On vue discord I got adviced to create .htaccess for this, sadly I am not skilled enough to create one, or even know to which folder store it. Also I had another one already in there since I am using php framework (Nette)

This is how I got it working for now :

> "publicPath: '/dist'" and "history:
> createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL)" where project is in "/dist"
> folder, so page goes [www.page.com/dist](http://www.page.com/dist). All work but. I go to
> "www.page.com" it redirects to "/dist" but when look in html it does
> not generate "/dist/css/chunk-vendors.css" so all imported css is
> missing. But when I hit refresh (going directly to [www.page.com/dist](http://www.page.com/dist))
> chunk-vendors.css is loaded. By default vendors.css is not in
> generated index.html so I guess its done by js. So i got evil thought
> of just paste that vendors.css link manually to my production
> index.html aand it works, althought when going to /dist url directly I
> end up with loading this style 2 times lol. Then I got even more evil
> thought and changed to 'history: createWebHistory("/")' , rebuilded
> for production and now i have nice [www.page.com](http://www.page.com) and even all imported
> styles are working (with that style link pasted in manually), just
> have some feeling I will burn in hell.

Comment: Seems like the issue could be in your PHP, where you "linked all js/css files to /dist folder manually", or in your `vue-router` config. Your question doesn't show enough context to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi there in vue router I changed
"history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),"
to 
history: createWebHistory('/'),

And it seems that issue stopped, but I just have one page I may broken something with that ? Php cant be source of this since when I coment js include, page is shown on "www.page.com" althought is blank since code is comented.

Comment: Attached also to question

Answer (score 8):

Here is a little summary of how a vue-cli project usually gets built and pushed to a server. and what kind of config is important and what 's their purpose. hope it gives you an idea of how to setup your project.

### Building with Vue Cli

This is how it works in a regular project to build with vue-cli:

**vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/final-sub-folder' : '',
  // ...
}
```

The above config sets a different site URL for dev and prod. The prod `/final-sub-folder` means that on the final URL in your distant server this sub-folder will be present (E.g. `https://example.com/final-sub-folder`).

when building with Vue Cli `npm run build` the output goes into `/dist` folder (by default) and the build is set for prod by default (so `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'`).

Now, if you try to go in that dist folder in your localhost (on Apache for instance), the vue-router using the same `publicPath` will fail because on your localhost `your-proj/dist` is a different base URL than `/final-sub-folder` as set in the config. So it will only work in the final server where the base url can be matched.

### Setting up vue-router

Your vue-router should always be set to (this config is for vue-router@next - for Vue 3):

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})
```

So that it follows the base URL you set in a single place, in your vue config.

*(notes: the createWebHistory removes the `#` in the URLs)*

### Adding a `.htaccess`

Regarding the `.htaccess`, it is a common practice to set up redirections in it so that on your final server, accessing `https://example.com/final-sub-folder/a-sub-page` directly will be redirected to your index.html that can load the vue-router which will handle the route matching of what you entered in the URL.
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Without this .htaccess, the Vue router cannot be reached from a sub-folder since it does not exist on the server (it's a virtual route using rewriting engine), it would result in a not found URL.

Here is a simple example of `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(js|css|map|jpe?g|svg|gif|png|eot|ttf|woff2?)(\?.*)?$ - [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* index.html [NC,QSA,L]
```

What is important in that is the last line redirecting anything to index.html (which is generated from your vue-cli build).
The previous line allows any asset file to not be redirected (no asset file should be handled by vue-router).

Hope it helps you understand! ;)

Comment: Saved my day, after wasting some hours...